# Override user-defined stylesheet in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, accessibility

I am trying to override a user defined stylesheet in IE. Specifically, font awesome icons and glyph icons do not show in any version of IE if the user loads their own style sheet for accessibility. I have tried including the !important value where needed but this doesn't take effect. I have also added a JS function to add inline styling with the font-family and !important with no success.

In the IE inspector, I can see that the :before selector of the font awesome or glyph icon have the content attribute crossed out but there is nothing overriding that property.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point of user-defined stylesheets is to be un-overwritable…

Comment: Please provide example markup, your stylesheet, and the user stylesheet that is loaded.

Comment: Bergi- I understand the point of user-defined stylesheets. In this case, all versions of IE fail to show any font-awesome icon or bootstrap glyph icon if a user defined style is loaded. I can add css for you but its really just the generic font-awesome css:

    .fa{
       font-family: 'fontAwesome' !important;
     }

When I add a generic user-defined stylesheet (nothing special), the !important seems to not take effect. The css for 
    .fa-times:before {
       content: "\f00d";
     } 
is crossed out in the inspector but nothing is being used in place of the content that is crossed out.

Comment: Also, I cannot share anything else per my company's privacy. But I can assure you that the user-defined stylesheet is very basic. All of other browsers have no issue displaying the icons with the user-defined stylesheet applied.

Comment: If you cannot share the real case, you should construct a minimal case that actually demonstrates the issue. It does not need to have any real content, “foobar” will do fine.

Comment: Does the user stylesheet have any font declarations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this issue was involved with IE not rendering the styles which had the `!important` attribute added. My issue was mainly using Font Awesome/Bootstrap's Font Glyphs with IE. I found a font from Adobe called Adobe Blank. This font is a clear font which takes up no visual space unless the user styles are overridden. Here is a link to the [font](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/adobe-blank/wiki/Home/).